# ASP.NET C# foreach only print last item in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, printing, foreach

I would like to show all valid links in a Literal Control container after clicking a button. However, only the last item in the list can be shown. I have used both for and foreach loop for testing but still not successful.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateButton.Click += ValidateButtonHandler;
        }

        private void ValidateButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> validPages = new List<string>();
            validPages.Add("www.google.com");
            validPages.Add("www.yahoo.com");
            validPages.Add("www.facebook.com");

            List<string> invalidPages = new List<string>();
            invalidPages.Add("www.gogle.com");
            invalidPages.Add("www.yaoo.com");
            invalidPages.Add("www.facbook.com");

            for (int i = 0; i < validPages.Count; i++)
            {
                ValidLinksBox.Text = "<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>";
            }

            foreach (string invalidPage in invalidPages)
            {
                InvalidLinksBox.Text = string.Format("<div class=\"alert success\"><p>{0}</p></div>", invalidPage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the aspx part:

```
<div class="admin-page">
      <h1>Valid Links:</h1>
        <asp:Literal ID="ValidLinksBox" runat="server" />
      <h1>Invalid Links:</h1>
        <asp:Literal ID="InvalidLinksBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="ValidateButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Validate links" />
  </div>
```

This is the result:

**Validate Links result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed concatenation operator. You are actually overwriting your string again n again in all of your iterations. You can replace the following:

```
ValidLinksBox.Text = "<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>";
```

with

```
ValidLinksBox.Text += ("<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>");
```

The better approach is to use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < validPages.Count; i++)
{
     builder.Append("<br/>");
     builder.Append(validPages[i]);
     builder.Append("<br/>");  
}

ValidLinksBox.Text =  builder.ToString();

builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string invalidPage in invalidPages)
{
    builder.Append("<div class=\"alert success\"><p>");
    builder.Append(invalidPage);
    builder.Append("</p></div>");
}

InvalidLinksBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

`StringBuilder` is better, more readable and faster than concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
ValidLinksBox.Text = "<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>";
```

with

```
ValidLinksBox.Text += "<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>"; // = replaced by +=
```

to append a string value - currently you're overwriting the content each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You have to append text otherwise it'll replace all text and print last text

You can do something like below or you can use `StringBuilder` to append texts and than set `InvalidLinksBox`'s text

```
InvalidLinksBox.Text += string.Format("<div class=\"alert success\"><p>{0}</p></div>", invalidPage);
```

Using [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.110).aspx) it contains `appendformat` method as well for more info go to that official link

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string invalidPage in invalidPages)
{
   str.Append(string.Format("<div class=\"alert success\"><p>{0}</p></div>", invalidPage));
}
InvalidLinksBox.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the text in the textbox, Please try the below code.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < validPages.Count; i++)
            {
                ValidLinksBox.Text += "<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing value with every iteration , try to save the value before next iteration come

```
        StringBuilder sb1= new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2= new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < validPages.Count; i++)
        {
            sb1.Append("<br/>" + validPages[i] + "<br/>");
        }
        ValidLinksBox.Text = sb1.ToString();
        foreach (string invalidPage in invalidPages)
        {
            sb2.Append(string.Format("<div class=\"alert success\"><p>{0}</p></div>", invalidPage));
        }
        ValidLinksBox.Text = sb2.ToString();
```